# Django with postgresql is getting slower and slower to create and save objects

Tags: django, postgresql

With Django 4.2.2 and Posgresql 15.3, I have to migrate data from another database.
Basically, I am doing something like that for each of the 1,500,000 rows I have to migrate:

```
try:
    asset = Asset.objects.get(otherdb_pk=otherdb_pk)
except Asset.DoesNotExist:
    asset = Asset(otherdb_pk=otherdb_pk)
asset.creation_date = a date from old database
asset.modification_date = a date from old database
asset.flag = a boolean from old database
asset.serial = a string from old database
asset.quantity = an integer from old database
asset.save()
```

Note that I do not want to use `bulk_create()` because I plan to get the generated primary key at once for other processing.

The database I read (it is on a separate server) can give me 500 rows per second, this is stable over the time.
At Django side, with a NVMe disk, the first 10,000 rows are copied at the speed of 500 inserts/seconds, after 100,000 copies the speed is 100 inserts/s and I stopped migration when it gradually went to 20 inserts/s.

I tried :

- Wait a little and restart my batch at the point it was stopped (I still got 20 inserts/s)
- Restart postgresql
- Run without transactions
- Run without indexes
- Fully recreate the database

But I have still the problem. I checked postgresql log file, but I found nothing interesting.

Do you have an idea why this happen and how can I solve that ?

Comment: Perhaps everything is run in a single transaction.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in how this code is called.  Please show us the full code.

Comment: Also show us the model definition for `Asset`.

Comment: Have you tried a local postgresql server? If the local server runs fast and stable, then it must the remote server or the network. Anyway, you can still try dump the local server and restore to the remote.

Comment: did you try creating records asynchronously?

Comment: I think the problem might be with the `get()` lookup. The more records you have, the slower it will be. If you dont have indexes (as you mentioned), then such lookup will be very slow. If you have indexes, then it should be a bit faster, but the index needs to be rebuild every after every index again (?)

Comment: if @yedpodtrzitko is right that because of ```get()``` lookup, the query is getting slow then a simple code trick would work, just create a set at the initial of the script and keep adding all the pk into it and check the presence of pk in that set but for this, your machine should have enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

It was stupid simple : I forgot to put an index on field `otherdb_pk` !

The more rows I had in the table the more postgresql had to search, it explains why it was getting slower and slower.